How to inject HTML into document.documentElement.innerHTML without closing the <body> tag
I have about 100 lines of boilerplate HTML that every file on my site begins with. It contains the following elements:
<!-- START OF BOILERPLATE TEXT -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta ...>
  <link href="..." rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="..."></script>
  <title>MY_TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div> Page banner ... </div>
  <hr>
<!-- END OF BOILERPLATE TEXT -->

I'd like to minimize the actual amount of boilerplate code needed for each page, and I've come up with the following solution:


<!-- Line 1 of actual code will load external script:

     <script src="/test/scripts/boot.js"></script> 

     For this demo I'm inlining it.   -->

<script>
  async function boot(title) {

    // Will insert header boilerplate in document.documentElement.
    // Actual code will fetch boilerplate code from server.

    const my_demo = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- ****************** page-specific <head> stuff ***************** -->
    <title>${title}</title>
  <!-- ****************** end page-specific stuff    ***************** -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Banner injected by boot.js</h1>
    <hr> <!-- end of page banner -->
    <!-- ****************** begin page content ***************** -->
`;

    try {
      document.documentElement.innerHTML = my_demo;
    } catch (my_error) {
      document.write('Error: ', my_error);
    }
  }
</script>

<!-- Line 2 of actual code will invoke boot() -->

<script>boot("Test Title")</script>

<!-- Now we begin adding our body html -->

<p>
  This is the actual content of the page. It should appear under the injected H1 and HR.
</p>



Here is the way I want it to look:

The boot() script appears to correctly insert my <head> and banner html, but my "actual content" doesn't appear underneath. According to the Safari debugger, there was a </body> tag inserted after the last line inserted by boot(). How can I prevent that?
Update: It's important that the boilerplate HTML be injected first. The remainder of the content is sometimes very long, which causes nothing but unstyled text to appear for several seconds before the banner is painted and the text is restyled.

I am sorry to tell, but doing this on the frontend is just an overhead, it's an easy job to do server-side, in addition you can profit from hard-links, proper SEO, and not having a bloated interface will quicly be a major plus.

When you insert text into the DOM (your .innerHTML = my_demo), the browser will close off any elements in order to keep the DOM as correct as it can. Which is why you are seeing a </body> that you did not put there.
Here is an example of doing what I think you are asking, by surrounding your real HTML body in an element (<main> in my example) with an id unique enough not to be found in your HTML otherwise. "MainHtmlToBeAppended" in my example.
Then you can retrieve your HTML and include with your my_demo string when setting .innerHTML.
I use "defer" in the script tag to ensure the DOM is loaded before trying to access it.
Note that I moved the boot("Test Title") invocation into the .js file, but you could leave it in your html file if you prefer. It just keeps the "extra" content in your .html file to a minimal single <script> line.


boot("Test Title")


function boot(title) {

    // Will insert header boilerplate in document.documentElement.
    // Actual code will fetch boilerplate code from server.

    const my_demo = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- ****************** page-specific <head> stuff ***************** -->
    <title>${title}</title>
  <!-- ****************** end page-specific stuff    ***************** -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Injected by boot.js</h1>
    <hr> <!-- end of page header -->
    <!-- ****************** begin page content ***************** -->
`;

    // EDIT Get the "real" content
    let mainHtml = document.querySelector( "#MainHtmlToBeAppended" ).innerHTML

    try {
      // EDIT Append the "real" content with the my_demo string
      // document.documentElement.innerHTML = my_demo;
      document.documentElement.innerHTML = my_demo + mainHtml;
    } catch (my_error) {
      // EDIT Better to set .innerHTML than .write()
      // document.write('Error: ', my_error);
      document.documentElement.innerHTML = `MY ERROR: ${my_error}`;
    }
}
<!-- Note: test.js would contain the Javascript shown in the snippet -->
<script defer src="test.js"> </script>

<!-- Now we begin adding our body html -->

<main id="MainHtmlToBeAppended">
  <p>
    This is the actual content of the page. It should appear under the injected H1 and HR.
  </p>
</main>




What/where is test.js?

Sorry, the name is a remnant of my test environment. It is the javascript in the code snippet, which is your code with my changes that I described. You obviously can call the file anything you want, as long as you change the filename in the script tag. If you look for the comments marked with EDIT you can see my changes with comments.

Something I didn't mention and should have is that it's important for the boilerplate to be inserted before the main part of the body. I previously used <body onload="boot()"> and for some of my very large files there was a long delay with raw/unstyled text and no banner, which was an ugly experience. By inserting the boilerplate HTML first I eliminated all of the repainting. I'll continue to see how I can use parts of your solution...

I didn't know about <main> before now. Seems like a good use for it.

document.documentElement.innerHTML rewrites the entire HTML element, including the <head> and <body>.
If you want to keep the existing contents, you can use insertAdjacentHTML. Here is the correct code:


async function boot(title) {
  const headContent = `
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>${title}</title>
  `;

  const bodyContent = `
    <h1>Injected by boot.js</h1>
    <hr> <!-- end of page header -->
  `;

  // Insert into head
  document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', headContent);
  
  // Insert into body without replacing existing content
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', bodyContent);
}

boot("Test Title");




At the time boot() runs, there isn't any existing content. That comes afterwards (see "Now we begin adding our body html" at end of my demo). If I'm wrong about that, please explain.
